# Gather input data from AngularJS directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this input form http://plnkr.co/edit/WiQrA6ITwkLzv1zuZR1n. Each row has its own data gathered. How can I combine all these documents into one array. This array will be pushed to DB.

Comment: Isn't the array just `$scope.languages`?

Comment: @tymeJV yes but it appears to be empty

Comment: @tymeJV Yes, I should populate languages array with input values. It is empty. I tried to push the object into the array, but it failed, so I removed that part.